# Use basicHttpBinding with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am trying to follow the How-To Guide 
here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx

However with step 2:

> In the Configuration Editor, in the Configuration section, expand
>   Service and then expand Endpoints. Select the first node [Empty Name].
>   Set the name attribute to BasicHttpEndpoint.

My Service node can not be expanded and there is no service setup? 
I have created a new webservice. then right clicked the Edit WCF Configuration?

Comment: The article you referenced doesn't seem that good. Try following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx) article instead.

Comment: You really dont need to do the steps as said rather you can just copy the config section in the article you have been following and paste it in your config. The Svc editor is a UI tool to make the configuration easy or you can just hand craft your config file

Comment: Do you use VS 2008 and target framework set to .Net 3.5? But in any case better way is to open config file in a text editor and edit all configurations there.